# Weather API giving this [ 401 (Unauthorized)] error

Tags: angular, ionic2

I am using a simple web API to get weather details for the latitude and longitude (getting latitude and longitude i am using Geolocation plug in)  I am not getting the required response but instead a 401 Error. Am I doing anything wrong?

Here is the error message

[image: Here is the error message].

Here is my code:

```
weatherForLocation(latitude, longitude){
     return new Promise(resolve => {
      this.http.get("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=" + latitude + "&lon=" + longitude + "&appid=<bfab95ebe3bbb8966c54139aefd539b4>").map(res => res.json())
       .subscribe(data => {
         this.data = data;
         resolve(this.data);
       })
     })
   }
```

Comment: Have you read this? https://openweathermap.org/faq

Comment: tried setting api id without `<` ? I suggest you try the api with a rest client to get the auth format right

Comment: Thanks you suraj Its working fine